# What is a telemetry event in the Language Server Protocol specification

Tags: language-server-protocol

In the Language Server Protocol specification, a telemetry notification is is sent from the server to the client to ask the client to log a **telemetry event**. I would like to know what a telemetry event is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Telemetry is used to gather data on the use of the language server. Telemetry events are usually data sent to report general usage information,  track how often features are used, start-up time, processing time etc.